# Trouble making an image appear on mouseover in HTML using button and image map

Tags: html, image, dictionary, button, mouseover

I'm sorry if I will ask silly questions, but do you know, what is missing in my code, to make an image appear when the mouse passes on a button or over coords? I am trying two ways, one is by putting the coordinates on an image map, but then I don't really know how to make the image appear where the map coordinates are. The other, is by putting a button, and using mouseover, and I don't really know how to make the image appear there aswell, it's for sure something very simple that is wrong or missing, but I don't know yet :-| it would be awesome to figure that out, thank you in advance for your help!

```
<map name="mymap">
        <area target="rec" coords="1130,256,1200,304" shape="rect" href="index2.html" onmouseover="visuel15.jpg">
    </map>
```

the other is:

```
    <button type="button" height="100" width="100" coords="1130,256,1200,304" onmouseover="button15.jpg;">
    </button>
```

I was expecting the image to appear, but probably something is wrong in the syntax, and in the attributes I am using.